# Laravel 5 assets and lang folder in separate modules

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am trying to split my application out into seperate "modules".

I am not sure whether to leave the assets folder where it is and put everything in there for every module or how I would go about giving each module their own assets folder.

What is the best approach and what would I have to do in order to access the assets folders from each module?

Here is my directory structure so far:

[image]

Also am I right to put a Requests folder in each module?

Here is there relevant composer.json section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Modules"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
},
```

Comment: This is a very valid question, but ultimately, it boils down to what you prefer. There's no correct way of doing it (though arguable some clearly wrong). I would suggest posting the question on e.g. the Laracasts forum.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Packages](http://laravel.com/docs/master/packages) section in the official Laravel documentation. It has sections on keeping things like translation files and other assets in your package, and publishing them when including your package in your applications.